# Java count occurrence of each item in an sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, find-occurrences

I have an Array of Strings and want to count the occurrences of any single String.

I have already sorted it. (It's a long Array and I wanted to get rid of the O(n²)-loop)

Here my code.. obviously it runs out in an ind.outOfB. exc.. the reason is clear but I donno how to solve..

```
for (int i = 0; i < patternsTest.length-1; i++) {
        int occ=1;
        String temp=patternsTest[i];
        while(temp.equals(patternsTest[i+1])){
            i++;
            occ++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use `Map<String, Integer>`?

Comment: I need the raw counts.. i dont know if i would create a Map only for that...

Comment: Why wouldn't you? It'd be faster, and easier to modify in the future.

Comment: Do you not want to use a Map for efficiency? by sorting you are losing out on a lot of efficiecy to start with, using a map means you don't need to presort.  But if you really don't want to use a map just explain the reasons, or I guess just say so :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This would be a good place for a HashMap, the key would be the Word, and the value the Number of times it occurs.  The `Map.containsKey` and `Map.get` methods are constant time lookups which are very fast.

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < patternsTest.length; i++) {
    String word=patternsTest[i];
    if (!map.containsKey(word)){
        map.put(word,1);
    } else {
        map.put(word, map.get(word) +1);
    }
}
```

As a side benefit you don't even need to sort beforehand!

Comment: This is a good answer, however I would change the declaration to the parent class  Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>(); http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-2nd-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683

Comment: but do the .containsKey() iterate over the whole Map? and the existing entry will be overwritten everytime..? seems to be inefficient this way.. Not saying that it is a bad aproach..

Comment: The containsKey is O(1) search.  Which means it will not iterate over the entire map, it's more akin to indexing into an array than a full search.  I'll update the answer with this as well.

Comment: How efficient are you looking for? You can make this slightly faster with an extra line of code if you would like me to put that version up instead of this

Comment: Nice question :P .. everybody was looking for the fastest, right? ;) its enough so far.. I think a workin version of my approach would been slower.. with all the sorting and bla. Thank you very much :)

Comment: From your last answer (that you deleted so I can't comment on it): IMO the question can be open and answered but not by giving direct code or by straightly giving the solution, instead driving OP to understand how to solve this. Please refer to [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/182862).

Comment: He had already shown some effort and code, which made it much less offensive in my eyes. giving someone an algorithm is a fair hint imo, but in this case the algorithm has so many solutions its trivial to find, so I just added it in.  Ultimately I agree with you though, so I deleted the answer.  It's just the morning here and sometimes I just go on autopilot ;) nice link though, I'll be using that to in the future to comment on questions like this one

Answer (score 4):

You can use Java HashMap:

```
Map<String, Integer> occurrenceOfStrings = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for(String str: patternsTest)
{
    Integer currentValue = occurrenceOfStrings.get(str);
    if(currentValue == null)
        occurrenceOfStrings.put(str, 1);
    else
        occurrenceOfStrings.put(str, currentValue + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not have index out of bounds:

```
String[] patternsTest = {"a", "b"};
for (int i = 0; i < patternsTest.length-1; i++) {
    int occ=1;
    String temp=patternsTest[i];
    while(temp.equals(patternsTest[i+1])){
        i++;
        occ++;
    }
}
```

You can cause an Index Out of Bounds by changing the data to:

```
String[] patternsTest = {"a", "a"};
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try a map and only one loop

```
Map<String, Integer> occurences = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
String currentString = patternsTest[0];
Integer count = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < patternsTest.length; i++) {
    if(currentString.equals(patternsTest[i]) {
        count++;
    } else {
        occurrences.put(currentString, count);
        currentString = patternsTest[i];
        count = 1;
    }
}
occurrences.put(currentString, count);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Guava Multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) solution (two lines of code):

```
Multiset<String> multiset = HashMultiset.create();
multiset.addAll(Arrays.asList(patternsTest));

//Then you could do...
multiset.count("hello");//Return count the number of occurrences of "hello".
```

We could use it both sorted and un-sorted arrays. Easy to maintain code.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
public int cantOccurences(String pattern, String[] values){
  int count = 0;

  for (String s : values) {
    count +=  (s.replaceAll("[^".concat(pattern).concat("]"), "").length());
  }
return count;
}
```